# Can't use local annotation processor in Android kotlin project

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, kapt

I have an AS3 / gradle plugin 3 project where we recently introduced a local simple annotation processor. Works fine with gradles annotationProcessor dependancy directive.

I started adding Kotlin code and moved all annotationProcessor directives to kapt ones. Glide and logan-square use annotation processors with Kotlin without a problem, but our local AP project can't be executed by kapt:

```
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
Using Kotlin incremental compilation

e: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Error reading configuration file
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:309)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toCollection(_Collections.kt:1042)
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toMutableList(_Collections.kt:1075)
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toList(_Collections.kt:1066)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.loadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:160)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:377)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:368)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:133)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:303)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:213)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:512)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:399)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:889)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:916)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:888)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:398)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor not found in /Users/kread/git/bgo/myrmecophaga-2.0/ejecta-v8/v8annotations-compiler/build/libs/v8annotations-compiler.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:144)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:152)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:304)
    ... 55 more


:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
```

The created JAR file has the necessary META-INF JAR entry though:

```
# jar tf /Users/kread/git/bgo/myrmecophaga-2.0/ejecta-v8/v8annotations-compiler/build/libs/v8annotations-compiler.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ag/
ag/boersego/
ag/boersego/v8annotations/
ag/boersego/v8annotations/compiler/
ag/boersego/v8annotations/compiler/V8AnnotationProcessor$1.class
ag/boersego/v8annotations/compiler/V8AnnotationProcessor$AccessorTuple.class
ag/boersego/v8annotations/compiler/V8AnnotationProcessor$AnnotationHolder.class
ag/boersego/v8annotations/compiler/V8AnnotationProcessor.class
META-INF/services/
META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
```

Excerpt from main module build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // gazillions of compile / api / ...
    api project(':ejecta-v8:v8annotations')
    kapt project(':ejecta-v8:v8annotations-compiler')
}
```

Module v8annotations build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {}
```

Module v8annotations-compiler build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile project(':ejecta-v8:v8annotations')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I'm stumped :(

Comment: As @tynn suggested, killing the Gradle daemons (specifically, Java processes `GradleDaemon` and `KotlinCompileDaemon`) should help. You can find its PIDs using the `jps` shell command.
Please also check the example about how to use project-local annotation processors and check if you are missing something https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/kotlin-code-generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues several times. I tried a combination of

```
pkill gradle
pkill java
```

and deleting the android studio setup of *.idea/workspace.xml* and the **.iml* files. It appeared to be a cached state which resulted in this issue.

Comment: Thanks! It was enough to kill the gradle daemon (pkill gradle).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was enough to run

```
gradlew --stop
```

from AndroidStudio console

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
pkill gradle 
clean project 
make project
```